# What does an antenna actually measure? The magnitude of the electric field, or the real component of the complex phasor representation?

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, mathematics, antennas

**I'm in the process of writing a physics simulation code, involving some antenna modeling. In the process of doing so, I've realized that I'm not so confident in my understanding of what an antenna *actually* does. This deficit in my understanding is exemplified by the following problem.**

---

I have a simple dipole antenna, in an almost completely radio-silent environment. I record the voltage measured across the antenna at some sampling rate, and plot the distribution of voltage magnitudes (i.e. the absolute value of each sample). Since the antenna is in a radio-silent environment, the voltage observed is entirely due to [thermal (i.e. "Johnson-Nyquist") noise](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Johnson%E2%80%93Nyquist_noise).

Many texts treat this by modeling the electric field due to the thermal noise as a complex phasor, whose components are independent and identically Gaussian distributed (arising, of course, from the central limiting behavior of a large ensemble of contributing atoms or molecules). They then take the voltage measured at the antenna to be the **real part of the complex phasor** (corresponding to the magnitude of the "in-phase" part of the electric field), hence the voltages are Gaussian distributed, and their magnitudes folded-Gaussian distributed.

Here's where my confusion arises. In practice, the electric field at any point in space is a $3$D vector, of course, and I would expect the central limiting behavior of the thermal noise contribution of a large ensemble of atoms/molecules to yield a $3$D vector whose components are independent and identically Gaussian distributed. I had *thought* that an antenna measured **the magnitude of the electric field** directly (and, in fact, this is precisely what is written in many texts). The magnitude of the electric field (and, consequently, the absolute value of the voltage values) can then easily be shown to be distributed according to a "$3$D" Rayleigh (in the same way the magnitude of a bivariate-Gaussian distributed $2$D vector follows a Rayleigh distribution).

---

**My Question.** Does an antenna measure the real part of the complex phasor representation of the electric field, or directly measure its magnitude (in general)? Why?

The fact that the voltages measured are Gaussian distributed, and their magnitudes folded-Gaussian distributed, seems to conflict with my understanding that antennas measure the magnitude of the electric field.

Comment: You have to follow the convention as stated in the texts that you are using. Many texts simply take the convention that the imaginary parts are physically not there, just a mathematical ghost to simplify the computation. You can, of course, also use another convention in which the magnitude is the correct descriptor, but then all the formulæ will have to be adjusted to take that into account.

Comment: @naturallyInconsistent Thanks for the input. So, to clarify, the voltage measured at the antenna is proportional to the magnitude of the electric field (and, depending upon convention, to the amplitude of the complex phasor)? Or is it that the voltage measured at the antenna is proportional to the amplitude of the complex phasor (and, depending upon convention, the electric field magnitude)?